# R combining multiple Matrix in to one

Tags: r

I have a set of matrix named gof_i_j where i= 1 -5 and j= 1-25 (i.e.from gof_1_1 to gof_5_25). So in total i have 125 matrix each with 1 column and 20 rows. I want  to combine all the matrix in to one along the column. I know I can use cbind(). But I don't want to type all the names. Any simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for example:

```
do.call(cbind,mget(ls(pattern ="gof_[1-5]_[0-9]+"))
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, I would like to get the matrix named gof_1_1, gof_2_1, gof_3_1, gof_4_1, gof_5_1 only. But when I use 
ls(pattern ="gof_[1-5]_[1]) it returns all matrix which has 1 (eg: gof_1_21 or gof_2_18). How can I select the above mentioned list of matrix?

Comment: @user3420448 try this `ls(pattern='gof_[1-5]_1$')`

Comment: @user3420448 please avoid to ask many questions in in the same one and   also avoid to ask questions in the comment. Try by your own if you can't you should ask in a  a new question. Please remove the above comment.